# Is there a word that combines the meanings of "not practical" and "not useful"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

For some particular treatment, in a specialized topic, I wanted to say that it's not practical as well as not useful. Is there just one word for that?

Comment: The question title and the question body are asking for two different things. Two *opposite* things, in fact, so that the current answer "useless", which answers the question in the body just fine, reads ridiculous when looking at the question in the title. Besides, negating "practical *and* useful" won't necessarily get you "not practical *and* not useful".

Comment: It is hard to think of something that is practical and **useless**.

Comment: @RegDwigнt edited title to conform to content of question

Comment: @Oldcat: “practical and useless”?  How about eyeglasses with flat glass (non-prescription) “lenses”?  They’re every bit as practical as vision-correcting spectacles, but (aside from secondary effects; e.g., altering your *appearance*, as a fashion accessory) useless.  How about putting on sunscreen when you’re going out at night?  How about a voice-activated self-destruct mechanism anywhere other than a sensitive military facility?  Nothing personal, but how about a pet cat (in a household that doesn’t have a mouse problem)?

Comment: If it designed as a fashion accessory, it is useful as a fashion accessory, if not  useful as a vision correction device.

Answer (score 2):

Why not **[useless](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/useless)**?

> having no practical use or advantage

Answer (score 1):

The word [*impractical* actually has both of those meanings.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/impractical)

> 1. not practical or useful